# How to add noConflict to a JS module pattern?

Tags: module, design-patterns, jquery

I use the following pattern in my JS:

```
var lib =
{
  module_one:
  {
      init: function () {
          ...
      }
  },
  module_two:
  {
      init: function () {
          ...
      }
  }
};
```

Question is, whats the best way to add:

```
(function ($) {          
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

I tried to put it around the var lib, but that didnt work. To add it inside each function worked, but seems a bit messy..?

Is it possible to add it to the init: function($) somehow?

Quite new on jQuery, so if you have any other suggestions around this pattern, let me know :-)

Comment: What is `lib` intended to be, a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can do this:

```
(function() {
    var global, lib, oldlib;

    // We call this anonymous scoping function directly, so we know that
    // within it, `this` is the JavaScript global object. Grab a
    // local reference to it so we can use it within functions that get
    // called via dotted notation and so have different `this` values.
    global = this;

    // Remember any value that already exists for the `lib` property
    // of the global
    oldlib = global.lib;

    // Define our lib, assigning it to a local variable
    lib = {
        /* ...your stuff as usual, plus: */

        noConflict: function() {
            global.lib = oldlib;
            return lib;
        }
    };

    // Publish our lib externally on the global object
    global.lib = lib;
})();
```

...which can then be used like this:

```
var alias = lib.noConflict();
```

Here's how that works:

1. We define a scoping function and then immediately call it.
2. Within the scoping function, we grab the `this` value as a variable called `global`. This will be the JavaScript global object because of the way we're calling the scoping function. (The global object on browsers is `window`, but there's no need to limit this to browsers, hence getting `global` this way).
3. The first thing we do is save any old value the `lib` property of the global object had, in a local variable in our scoping function called `oldlib`.
4. We set up our new value for `lib`.
5. Our `noConflict` function restores the earlier value of the `lib` property, and returns our lib reference so someone can use it as an alias.

BTW, when you use a scoping function, you can also switch over to using named functions rather than anonymous ones, which [has several benefits](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html). Here's the above updated to use a named function for `noConflict`.

```
(function() {
    var global, lib, oldlib;

    // We call this anonymous scoping function directly, so we know that
    // within it, `this` is the JavaScript global object. Grab a
    // local reference to it so we can use it within functions that get
    // called via dotted notation and so have different `this` values.
    global = this;

    // Remember any value that already exists for the `lib` property
    // of the global
    oldlib = global.lib;

    // Define the functions for our lib. Because they're defined
    // within our scoping function, they're completely private
    function lib_noConflict() {
        global.lib = oldlib;
        return lib;
    }

    // Define our lib, publishing the functions we want to be public
    lib = {
        /* ...your stuff as usual, plus: */

        noConflict: lib_noConflict
    };

    // Publish our lib externally on the global object
    global.lib = lib;
})();
```